# Automatically requesting data from the server with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm using the owl-carousel plugin for jquery, and the data is derived from a django view returning JSON.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        jsonPath : '/example/json_response',
        jsonSuccess : customDataSuccess,
            navigation : true, 
            slideSpeed : 300,
            paginationSpeed : 400,
            singleItem:true,
            autoPlay : 3000
      });


      function customDataSuccess(data){
        var content = "";
        for(var i in data["items"]){

           var name = data["items"][i].name;

           content += "<div class='item'>" + name + "</div>";
        }
        $("#owl-demo").html(content);
      }
```

Now this works fine, but how would I change it to keep requesting the server for new data?
The JSON I'm sending changes over time, and I can't figure out how to tell the owl-carousel API to keep requesting the server.

I tried putting the owlCarousel() call in a setInterval() function, but it still only takes the JSON once, and only uses the initial JSON response...

How could this be solved?
Thanks in advance

Comment: use `$(".owl-carousel").data('owlCarousel').reinit(newOptions)` might help http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing

Comment: @Satpal So that works, thanks. But, when the response returns, you can see the page sort of "refreshing" itself... That's because the DOM element is creating itself all over, right? Is there a way to avoid this, so that the transition will be invisible for the user?